# Weird warning when using QNetwork

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I'm using a [file downloader class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-downloadmanager-downloadmanager-cpp.html), I have modified it a little bit, although the issue occurs in the original class as well.

Here it is:

> WARNING: QObject::connect: Cannot connect
>   (null)::stateChanged(QNetworkSession::State) to
>   QNetworkReplyHttpImpl::_q_networkSessionStateChanged(QNetworkSession::State)
>   (kernel\qobject.cpp:2614, class QMetaObject::Connection __cdecl
>   QObject::connect(const class QObject *,const char *,const class
>   QObject *,const char *,enum Qt::ConnectionType))

As you can see it's related to the `connect()` method. To make it clear, I've removed all `connect()` calls, but that didn't stop warning to show up.

The error itself does not affect the functionality of the code.

Perhaps it's some kind of Qt bug? Any possibility I could suppress this error from being shown?

My QT version: 5.5.1 running with Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Bug and has been solved in Qt5.6: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTIFW-822

Comment: Thats what I thought. Thanks